# How to convert process / cpu core based upon MIPS?

Tags: computer-architecture

I want to know how can i find number of cpu cores/processor supported given i have the MIPS value?

For e.g I want to know the number of matching cores/processor to process speed of 18 triilion instructions / sec.

Comment: This will depend on the speed of the cores/processors. Then use division.

Comment: can we measure / predict speed based on matches per second measurement? like in DB case please read my replies below

Comment: It seems that you have a specific application in mind. Please add some details of this application by editing your question. 18 trln. is a lot. For any nontrivial application ensuring scalability across thousands of cores would be a challenge in itself.

Answer (score 2):

For a modern CPU there is no exact MIPS rating since it depends on the specific instruction stream, power saving mode, and other factors. As a reference number you may look at the [BogoMIPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BogoMips) rating that is calculated by the Linux kernel.

A desktop CPU core at 3GHz can process about 2 instructions per clock cycle *on average* resulting in a rating close to 6000 MIPS (or 6 billion instructions per second), therefore 18 trillion instructions would require about 3000 cores.

Comment: So if i read you correct 3000 cores running at 3Ghz would perform 18 trillion instructions per second. What is 1 unit relationship e.g 1 core= how many instructions?

Comment: So in this case the number of cores are dependent upon speed and # of instructions per processor. This number can never be fixed? Is 3000 cores reasonable talking about which hardware manufacture does this.

Comment: @if i have the value for number of matches per second in terms of DB can it help me get approx val for processor speed?

Comment: @user970533 3000 cores can be found in a compute cluster or a compute farm (3000 cores ~ 100-400 dual processor nodes). Large database machines from leading manufacturers have 20 to 50 times smaller core count.